# How to handle a large modulus?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am researching on Proth-numbers, i.e. numbers of the form $n :=h\cdot 2^k + 1$, where $h$ odd and $h<2^k$. There is a test:

> If there exists an $a$ such that $a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\equiv -1 \pmod n$, then $n$ is prime.

My problem is computing this modpower. Most programming languages have a fast powermod-function, but if $k$ is very large, it will still take a lot of time. So I wondered if there is a better way.

Since I do not know whether $n$ is prime or composite, I can't make a statement about possible divisors.
I would be glad already if I had the info that this congruence does NOT hold.
So, does anyone know whethere there are maybe sufficient or necessary conditions?

Comment: What is n here? Is it equal to $h\cdot 2^k + 1$?

Comment: @LucaArmstrong Yes. Sorry, I edited that in the answer.

Comment: No more efficient method for primality testing is known than to begin with a fermat-test or some variant closely related to this , perhaps after having applied trial division upto some reasonable limit. So no, to find Proth primes is not easier than to find any other kind of prime numbers with the same magnitude , but at least we have an efficient primality proof here.

Comment: Fortunately, in most cases , a quite small $a$ does the job if the Proth number is actually prime. But if we are unlucky , it can in fact be difficult to find it. Maybe , a good idea is to start with some very reliable primality test (Miller Rabin or BPSW)

Comment: When k is prime we have $$(a^h)^{2^{k-1}}\equiv h+(h+1)x\pmod{2^k-1}$$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee What is the x for?

Comment: Because $$y\equiv b\pmod m\implies y=mx+b$$

Comment: Rewriting we have :

$$(a^h)^{2^{k-1}}\equiv h\cdot 2^k\pmod{h\cdot 2^k+1}$$

Which is:

$$(a^h)^{2^{k-1}}=(h\cdot 2^k+1)x+h\cdot 2^k$$

Or ( if k is prime using Fermat's little theorem):

$$(a^{2^{k-1}})^h=(h\cdot 2+1)x+h\cdot 2\pmod k$$

Comment: @mathquester anything new found out ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I couldn't check it, yet. But thank you, I appreciate your help and will check this shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Comment: May be these facts from the book (number theory by Sierpinski) help you to filter the numbers you test and reduces the time of calculations:

1-Particular case where in $n=h\cdot 2^k+1$, $h=k$; in this case it can be shown that for any odd prime p there exist infinitely many number like h such that $p|h\cdot 2^h+1$.

Proof: If p is an odd prime and :

$n=(p-1)(k\cdot p+1)$

we will have:

$n\equiv -1 \bmod p$

and n is divisible by $(p-1)$

and due to Fermat little theorem $2^n\equiv 1 \bmod p$ and number $n=h\cdot 2^h+1$ will be divisible by p.

We can conclude that there are infinitely many composite numbers in the form $h\cdot2^h+1$ . These numbers are called Cullen numbers.The known Cullen prime numbers are with $h=1, 141, 4713, 5795, 6611, 18496, 32292, 32469, 59656, 90825, 262419, 361275, 481899, 1354828, 6328548$ and $6679881$. It has been shown that almost all Cullen numbers $C_n$ are composite!

2- In other case $h\neq k$, it can be shown there exist infinite numbers like h such that number $n=h\cdot 2^k+1 $ is composite.

Proof: We know $F_m=2^{2^m}+1$  for $m= 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ , $F_m $ is prime and $F_5=641 p$ , where $p>F_4=2^{16}+1$  is prime. Also $F_5$ is divisible by $p$ and we have:

$(p, F_5-2)=1 \Rightarrow (p, 2^{32}-1)=1$

Now due to Chinese remainder theorem there exists infinitely many natural numbers like k which satisfy following congruences:

$k\equiv 1[\bmod(2^{32}-1)\cdot 641]$

and:

$k\equiv -1\bmod p$

It can be proved that if natural number $k>p$ and satisfy these congruences then all numbers $k\cdot 2^n+1 $ are composite.